# Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I wanted to have a dual monitor setup, but it won't detect my 2nd monitor.
I already went into BIOS and enabled the onboard graphics as well as the surround view.

I've tried it before and it worked. The same mother board, processor, and video card. I only changed the HDD.

My Specs:

> Mobo: GA-A55M-DS2
>   Proc: AMD A4-3300 APU
>   Graphics Card: Asus EAH6570 Series
>   RAM: 4GB
>   OS: Win7

Comment: Did it work, you installed a hard drive without disconnecting any video cables, then it did not work/